# Inline transition duration weird behavior

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, react-transition-group

I'm making a floating up animation of a text with `CSSTransition`. It works, but only if I specify animation's duration in css file. What I want is to keep duration parameter in one place (js file) to keep code DRY. Right now I need to specify it in both css class and CSSTransition's `timeout` prop.

The problem is that when I uncomment inline style with duration, the animation first goes up, but then it goes backwards and it shouldn't. What am I missing? When `*-enter-active` class goes off the animated text should become hidden, because of the `diff` class. Maybe the browser doesn't re-calculate styles? Why does it work, when duration is specified in css and doesn't work when it is in `style` prop?

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/dhmk083/pen/NWqroLa). Uncomment line 20 in js file to see the bug.

```
const AnimatedDiff = ({value}) => {
  const [prev, setPrev] = React.useState(value)
  const diff = value - prev
  const diffSign = diff > 0 ? '+' : ''
  const diffStr = diffSign + diff

  const timeout = 800

  return (
    <CSSTransition 
      classNames='diff' 
      timeout={timeout} 
      in={diff > 0}
      onEntered={() => setPrev(value)}
    >
      <div 
        className='diff'
        // style={{transitionDuration: `${timeout}ms`}}
      >
        {diffStr}
      </div>
    </CSSTransition>
  )
}
```

```
.diff {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.diff-enter-active {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translate(0, -100%);
  transition: transform;
  transition-duration: 800ms;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it. I need to replace `visibility` prop with `display`. This does the trick. Also, `display: block` should be specified within a separate `.diff-enter` rule, not in a `.diff-enter-active`. So, styles become:

```
.diff {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}

.diff-enter {
  display: block;
}

.diff-enter-active {
  transform: translate(0, -100%);
  transition: transform;
}
```